# Display Grid does not work in Polymer correctly

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to make an responsive Grid which changes the order of elements when the container gets resized.

If the container gets bigger, then an element from the second row only gets in the row abouve if there is enough space. If there is not enough space the space between the elements gets bigger until the element from the second row can fit inside the first row.

[Here is a working example how it's realized without Polymer](https://jsfiddle.net/k27yc8aq/)

But the Problem is if I embed this inside a custom Polymer element. The space between two elements does not change. Is there any solution to this Problem?

**Here is my Polymer-Element:**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            .container {
                min-height: 400px;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
                justify-content: space-around;
                align-items: center;
                align-content: start;
            }

            .item {
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                margin: 5px;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        class TestElement extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'test-element';
            }

        }
        window.customElements.define(TestElement.is, TestElement);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: why flex:0 0 auto ? when parent is displayed as grid not flex ?  Does other style are applied ? such as size, background ?

Comment: @G-Cyr There are no other styles applied. What should I write instead?

Comment: @G-Cyr if I remove this line then everything stays the same

Comment: I meant, is background and height/width applied or is it only grid not being applied? Of course on plain html/css side your code is fine.

Comment: @G-Cyr There is only this element. I did not apply any other CSS settings (no backgrounds, or height/width sizes)

Comment: @ValentinGavran What browser are you using? I am not seeing any difference between the Polymer and non-Polymer versions. Here is a JSFiddle of the Polymer version. https://jsfiddle.net/stramel/rqbsjjjo/

Comment: @MichaelStramel I'm using the [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) Framework to create a Desktopapplication (I think it runs on Chromium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your issue is that you haven't set a display style on the host element:

> Custom elements are display: inline by default, so setting their width or height will have no effect. This often comes as a surprise to developers and may cause issues related to laying out the page. Unless you prefer an inline display, you should always set a default display value.

Source: [Custom Element Best Practices, Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices#set-a-host-display-style-eg-block--inline-block-flex-unless-you-prefer-the-default-of--inline)

I'm using Polymer 3 but it shouldn't really make any difference:

```
import {Element as PolymerElement} from './node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class TestElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return `
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
        .container {
          min-height: 400px;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
          justify-content: space-around;
          align-items: center;
          align-content: start;
        }
        .item {
          flex: 0 0 auto;
          margin: 5px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: green;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('test-element', TestElement);
```

Then "run it":

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="./test-element.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <test-element id="test"></test-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm seeing:

[image: Screencast]